# c# unicode to char - is there an equivalent of this in t-sql

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a unicode value that when I assign to char gets the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    char test = '\ue900'; //This makes test = 59648'.'
}
```

Is there a way to get 59648'.' in t-sql. I'm not even sure why there is a '.' behind the number?

Comment: If you mean in the debugger view, then I don't know why there is a '.' either (it's not acutally part of the character), but 59648 is just the decimal conversion of the hex number E900. And that particular unicode character doesn't seem to be assigned to anything as of now http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e900/index.htm

Comment: yeah, in the debugger. i tried the answer below but i don't get the 59648

Comment: @Rod You literally need the value 59648? Just use an INT then. Or a VARCHAR depending on what you're doing with it. Or you can cast the character to an INT after doing the conversion below.

Comment: @Rod Sorry for double post... it's incorrect to say you're not getting 59648 from the code below. You are. It's just that the NCHAR () function returns an NCHAR value, so you see the character for the int in UTF-16 encoding. E900, 59648, and the character are all equivalent in TSQL. In fact there are implicit conversions built in so you wouldn't necessarily need to cast.

Answer (score 1):

The NCHAR() function takes an integer and converts to the equivalent Unicode character.

```
SELECT NCHAR(0xE900)
```

There's some wrinkles depending on your DB collation settings so best to check the documentation as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/nchar-transact-sql